# How to select only rows that are not in another table without getting data of the other table - PLSQL

Tags: sql, join, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im trying to SELECT all rows from one table with a specific condition. Im using Oracle PLSQL.

I have two tables:

**Books**

- id
- name

**Page**

- id
- words
- book_id

One book can have multiple pages.
**I want to find all books that don't have any page with 50 words.**

The only solution I've found is to make a Left Outer Join and then filter by nulls.

```
Select * from Books b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Page p on b.id = p.book_id and p.words = 50
where p.words is null
```

I think its not a good solution, but it works, do you know any other way to do that?

I don't want to take any information about Pages. If I make a normal join and then I apply the condition I get N rows for a Book, and I only want to get 1 row for each Book

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust your `select` so it is only `b.*`.

Possibly a more common alternative is `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from Books b 
where not exists (select 1
                  from Page p 
                  where b.id = p.book_id and p.words = 50
                 );
```

The two methods should have similar performance characteristics.

Comment: "Not exists" was the condition I needed. I didn't know that I could use it in Oracle
Thanks!!!